# Receive telegram bot messages as user login in telethon

Tags: telethon

​
​I login to telethon as a user, but can't receive any message from a bot with username or new message events. And the list of messages is empty.

I using this code in python:

```py
...
messages = await client.get_messages('mybotid_bot')
...
```

In script, receive messages from other users.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Try updating it to get a better chance at useful answers. Make sure the accounts you're checking with are the ones you expect.